# How to add directory?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to add information to a directory is this the correct method of doing it? Seems to not be working

```
ADSearchResult.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties.Item("mobile").Add("5555555555")
ADSearchResult.GetDirectoryEntry().CommitChanges()
```

Comment: Does AD stand for ActiveDirectory?  You probably have to document your question a bit better.

Comment: Does the account that is running the app have permissions to update the AD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You called `GetDirectoryEntry()` twice. That means when you call `CommitChangegs()`, you're committing from a **different object** in memory than the one where you updated the phone number. Even if the two objects represent the same AD record, they're still different objects. Only one of them has your changes. You need to commit from the *same object* you updated:

```
Dim ADEntry = ADSearchResult.GetDirectoryEntry()
ADEntry.Properties.Item("mobile").Add("5555555555")
ADEntry.CommitChanges()
```